# Jquery dialog : Hide the button

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am using Jquery's dialog() method to create dialog.
I am creating buttons on the dialog while creating the dialog, using

```
      $("#divName").dialog({
            buttons:
            {
            "Cancel":{
```

I have one event on which I need to hide the button,but don't know which attributes to use.
Please tell me the attributes to hide button.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15):

If you're trying to hide the "cancel" button, try this.

```
$('.ui-dialog-buttonpane button:contains("cancel")').button().hide();
```

Comment: Had some trouble with this until I realized that the parameter ('cancel') is case sensitive (my button was labeled 'Cancel').

Answer (score 7):

When you create the dialog, you describe the buttons and the attributes of the buttons, so add an "id" attribute to the button:

buttons: [ { text: "Save", id: "btnId", click: function() { ... } } ]

You can then use the id as a jquery filter for the hide() and show() methods:

$("#btnId").hide()...

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
$('#divName').siblings('.ui-dialog-buttonpane').find('button').eq(n).hide();
```

where `n` is the number of the button in your dialog (starting from zero)

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
$("#divName").css("display","none");
```

Comment: that'll hide the whole dialog.

Comment: I've added a hint how you can give the button a ID so it is easier to access it. This way, only the button is hidden and not the entire dialog... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This will hide first button:

```
$('#divName').siblings('.ui-dialog-buttonpane').find('button:first').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below to get handle to all buttons and then loop through them to hide.

```
var buttons = $("#divName").dialog('option', 'buttons');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this jQuery selector to hide the "cancel" button. Adjust `childNodes` index according to your buttons order.

```
$('.ui-dialog-buttonset')[0].childNodes[0].hide();
```